# Fedora 28 and NVidia drivers

Tags: linux, fedora, nvidia

I am running Fedora 28 on a Lenovo W510. Nvidia Quadro FX880M. I have installed both RPMFusion and negativo repos to install the NVidia driver. Both result in the Nouveau driver still being used.

So, how to I use the NV driver and where do I download it from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RPMFusion has documented the process on their wiki: https://rpmfusion.org/Howto/NVIDIA
You probably need to remove the negativo repository to avoid conflicting packages with rpmfusion.

Also make sure to disable Secure boot in your BIOS/UEFI, otherwise the linux kernel will refuse to load the NVIDIA kernel module.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I went through the rpmfusion documentation and still had no luck. That's why I am asking for help here. I have already undid the negativo install, including disabling the repo. I do not see any reference to secure boot in my BIOS. II did a little more research and my Quadro FX 880M is no longer supported in the unified driver but is instead supported through legacy driver releases. Does this mean RPMFusion doesn't support this GPU? My card is supported by the 340.xx drivers. Let me know if you need more info. Thx.

Comment: Have you tried let it build the kernel module after installation. The build process happens in the background seperate from dnf. Alternatively you could try manually rebuilding the kernel module with kmod, and then regenerate the ramdisk with dracut.

Comment: No. I read about the compiling after install but didn't see anything happening after dnf install... I will try again and allow plenty of time for compiling. I will let you know how it works out.

Comment: I finally got it working. The guide I followed is here. https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2015/fedora-nvidia-guide/ In short, I downloaded a patched driver for the 4.17 kernel deleted and blacklisted nouveau and installed the patched driver in runlevel 3. Thanks for your help.